# Performance Issue with Pool method of multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a column in a data frame which consists of a list of item, I want to calculate the similarity of rows of that data frame  (that will be list in this case) with all other rows based on Fisher exact test. For this purpose, I want to use  **Pool** from python multiprocessing but it seems to be taking approx. same time as the traditional method (i.e using nested for-loop). Is there any way by which I can optimise the code?

Fisher test

```
def fisher_test(a, b, c, d):
    # do some stuff and return p value
```

Computation using nested for loop:

```
%%time
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())


universeSize = 13000
# gq_result_df is a data frame
for i, row in gq_result_df.iterrows():
    for j in range(i, gq_result_df.shape[0]):
        if(i==j):
            continue
        pval = fisher_test(row["module_genes"], gq_result_df.loc[j,"module_genes"], universeSize)
        # pval_matrix is a matrix in which we are storing the result
        pval_matrix[i,j] = pval
```

using Pool to parallelize the inner loop :

```
%%time

universeSize = 13000

import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

for i, row in range(0, gq_result_df.shape[0]):

    pval = [pool.apply(fisher_test, args = (row["module_genes"], 
                                                         gq_result_df.loc[j,"module_genes"], universeSize)) for j in range(i+1, gq_result_df.shape[0])]
    #print("pval:", pval)
    for j in range(i +1, fish_pval_mat.shape[0]):
        pval_matrix[i, j] = pval[j -i -1]

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Computation time when I run outer loop for 119 times

1. Without parallelization: 13 min
2. With the parallelization (using Pool): 12 min

How can I optimise the parallelization code to reduce the time? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where does `fisher_test` come from?  Did you define it yourself, or is it imported?

Comment: I defined it by myself @James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the use of `Pool.apply()` as it is a blocking call. Hence your execution is not parallel but sequential. Pool.apply() blocks until a result is available, making this just another implementation of the nested loop you mentioned. You submit one chunk to a subprocess, wait for it to be processed and then submit another - instead of submitting them all on one go.

I am not familiar with this particular algorithm and not sure if you can parallelise it - i.e. are chunks to be processed independent or do results of previous chunks affect the consecutive tasks, in which case this does not parallelise.

If it does parallelise, you could try `apply_async()` instead.  If you do this, then the interface changes a bit as your `pval` is no longer a list of results but a list of `AsyncResult` objects, and you need to loop through these and `get()` the actual result from your worker.

Comment: yes, ```apply_async()``` will work fine. However, a caveat with ```apply_async()```  is, the order of numbers in the result gets jumbled up indicating the processes did not complete in the order it was started.

Comment: No, it does not guarantee that - this is more or less the point of parallel processing. If you are interested in the order, you can send an index to your worker as a parameter in apply_async and then just return this unmodified in the result set.

Comment: Or even simpler in this case, the order in which your pval list is formed, is the order of submission. If you enumerate this in your for loop to get results, you will get at lest the ordinal number for free if this is enough.